# SQL Pivot with grouping and dynamic column names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've used pivot before but I can't figure out how to group by 2 columns and pivot while dynamically creating column names.

I have a table with data that's grouped by 2 columns, "unit" and "grouped" in my example below.  Each "unit" contains unique data and within each "unit" the data is further grouped and I want to turn this column data into rows for reporting purposes. There are also a fieldName column that indicates what each value is, however the field names are not static.

Sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE #test (
  fieldID int ,
  fieldName nvarchar(50),
  unit nvarchar(50),
  grouped int,
  value varchar(255)
);
INSERT INTO #test (fieldID, fieldName, unit, grouped, value) VALUES (1, 'uid',      'unit 1', 1, 'bob');
INSERT INTO #test (fieldID, fieldName, unit, grouped, value) VALUES (2, 'name',     'unit 1', 1, 'bob');
INSERT INTO #test (fieldID, fieldName, unit, grouped, value) VALUES (3, 'policy',   'unit 1', 1, '123456');
INSERT INTO #test (fieldID, fieldName, unit, grouped, value) VALUES (4, 'adress',   'unit 1', 1, '123 Some st.');
INSERT INTO #test (fieldID, fieldName, unit, grouped, value) VALUES (1, 'uid',      'unit 1', 2, 'willie');
INSERT INTO #test (fieldID, fieldName, unit, grouped, value) VALUES (2, 'name',     'unit 1', 2, 'william');
INSERT INTO #test (fieldID, fieldName, unit, grouped, value) VALUES (3, 'policy',   'unit 1', 2, '45678');
INSERT INTO #test (fieldID, fieldName, unit, grouped, value) VALUES (4, 'adress',   'unit 1', 2, '456 some other st.');
INSERT INTO #test (fieldID, fieldName, unit, grouped, value) VALUES (5, 'nickname', 'unit 1', 2, 'Bill');
INSERT INTO #test (fieldID, fieldName, unit, grouped, value) VALUES (1, 'uid',      'unit 2', 1, 'djoe');
INSERT INTO #test (fieldID, fieldName, unit, grouped, value) VALUES (2, 'name',     'unit 2', 1, 'jane');
```

Is there a way to pivot this:

| fieldID | fieldName | unit | grouped | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | uid | unit 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | name | unit 1 | 1 | bob |
| 3 | policy | unit 1 | 1 | 123456 |
| 4 | adress | unit 1 | 1 | 123 Some st. |
| 1 | uid | unit 1 | 2 | willie |
| 2 | name | unit 1 | 2 | william |
| 3 | policy | unit 1 | 2 | 45678 |
| 4 | adress | unit 1 | 2 | 456 some other st. |
| 5 | nickname | unit 1 | 2 | Bill |
| 1 | uid | unit 2 | 1 | djoe |
| 2 | name | unit 2 | 1 | jane |

into this so that the groupings on unit/grouped are performed and the column names in the output table are dynamically generated based on the values in fieldName?

Like this:

| unit | uid | name | policy | address | nickname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| unit 1 | bob | bob | 123456 | 123 Some St. |  |
| unit 1 | willie | william | 45678 | 456 some other st. | Bill |
| unit 2 | jdoe | jane |  |  |  |

EDIT

This appears to do the grouping, but are the dynamic column names possible?

```
SELECT * FROM(
  SELECT [fieldName], [unit], [grouped], [value] FROM #test
) t
PIVOT(
  MIN([value])
  FOR fieldName IN([uid], [name], [policy], [adress], [nickname])
) as pivot_table;
```

Comment: not in straight sql.  you need to use a stored procedure or script to create the SQL statement as a string in a variable, then execute it

Comment: For dynamic column names, you need dynamic SQL. [Start here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/?utm_source=AaronBertrand).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)